# Overwrite table in Spark SqlContext

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

What is the recommended way to overwrite a table in Spark SqlContext?
Is it OK to directly call

```
modified_df.registerTempTable("same_table_name")
```

without dropping the table in sqlContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice would likely be to explicitly drop the table to avoid confusion. But, the above code will overwrite the table as you would expect.

Comment: I agree but that's in case you are using a regular RDMS. With Spark, you won't need the overhead. registerTempTable implies dropping if exists.